# (Turtle/Python3) How to make a while loop that's independently working forever in turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, turtle-graphics, infinite

So what I want to do, is display:
The distance of Alex from Alice is: (distance I calculated already)

I need this to be displayed on top of the screen.. forever,refreshing, kind of like PING statistics in games shows on top there..

I assume it would be a while loop? I need the rest of the program running while this is constantly displaying and refreshing..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my minimalist approach to this problem (well, not totally, I did throw in a couple of niceties):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT_SIZE = 24
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

def turtle_drag(turtle, other, x, y):
    turtle.ondrag(None)  # disable event hander in event hander
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    display.undo()  # erase previous distance
    distance = turtle.distance(other)
    display.write('Distance: {:.1f}'.format(distance), align='center', font=FONT)
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(other))  # make them always look
    other.setheading(other.towards(turtle))  # lovingly at each other
    turtle.ondrag(lambda x, y: turtle_drag(turtle, other, x, y))  # reenable

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)

display = Turtle(visible=False)
display.penup()
display.goto(0, screen.window_height() / 2 - FONT_SIZE * 2)
display.write('', align='center', font=FONT)  # garbage for initial .undo()

Alex = Turtle('turtle')
Alex.speed('fastest')
Alex.color('blue')
Alex.penup()

Alice = Turtle('turtle')
Alice.speed('fastest')
Alice.color('red')
Alice.penup()

turtle_drag(Alex, Alice, -50, -50)  # initialize position and event hander
turtle_drag(Alice, Alex, 50, 50)

screen.mainloop()
```

As you drag Alex or Alice, their center to center distance at the top of the screen updates.  This uses a separate, invisible, stationary turtle handling the display who does `.undo()` to erase a previous value and `.write()` to display a new one.  Making the turtles turn towards each other *after* the distance display is updated ensures they don't get trapped underneath the invisible display turtle (i.e. undragable) so they can even be postitioned atop the text:

[image]